# AngularJS : How to inject Controller into Service?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I want to inject One Controller to Service.

I use AngularJs and Laravel and glup-ng-annotate.

```
/* DialogController*/
    (function(){
        "use strict";

        angular.module("music.controllers").controller('DialogController', function( $scope, $mdDialog ){
            $scope.hide = function() {
                $mdDialog.hide();
            };
            $scope.cancel = function() {
                $mdDialog.cancel();
            };
            $scope.answer = function(answer) {
                $mdDialog.hide(answer);
            };
        });
    })();
```

And this is Service

```
/* Service */
(function(){
    "use strict";

    angular.module("music.services").factory('DialogService', function( $mdDialog, DialogController){

        return {
            fromTemplate: function(template, $scope ) {

                var options = {
                    controller: DialogController,
                    templateUrl: template
                };

                if ( $scope ){
                    options.scope = $scope.$new();
                }

                return $mdDialog.show(options);
            },

            alert: function(title, content){
                $mdDialog.show(
                    $mdDialog.alert()
                    .title(title)
                    .content(content)
                    .ok('Ok')
                    );
            }
        };
    });
})();
```

I have this error

**Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: DialogControllerProvider <- DialogController <- DialogService**

Comment: Factory / services can have their own controllers! You can't add/inject controllers to services / factory!

Comment: You're trying to put the cart in front of the horse.

Comment: Look this js code, Line 82 and 108, http://codepen.io/kyleledbetter/pen/gbQOaV

Comment: *"look at this code"* isn't a proper problem description. What exactly are you trying to do in words? Your concept is very backwards as others are all pointing out. See: [ask]

Comment: @charlietfl excuse me, I do not understand English well , I'm French

Comment: Then your best bet is to do some translations the same way others do here

Answer (score 2):

A service can be injected into a controller but the vice-versa is not possible. As the dependency injection in AngularJS supports injection of services in controllers.

Answer (score 2):

The controller should be injected by the `$mdDialog` service. Put quotes around the name, so that the `$mdDialog` service gets a string instead of a reference.

```
(function(){
    "use strict";

    angular.module("music.services")
      .factory('DialogService', function($mdDialog ̶,̶D̶i̶a̶l̶o̶g̶C̶o̶n̶t̶r̶o̶l̶l̶e̶r̶ ){

        return {
            fromTemplate: function(template, $scope ) {

                var options = {
                    //REPLACE this
                    //controller: DialogController,
                    //WITH this
                    controller: "DialogController",
                    templateUrl: template
                };

                if ( $scope ){
                    options.scope = $scope.$new();
                }

                return $mdDialog.show(options);
            },

            alert: function(title, content){
                $mdDialog.show(
                    $mdDialog.alert()
                    .title(title)
                    .content(content)
                    .ok('Ok')
                    );
            }
        };
    });
})();
```

In this case the `options` object is passed to the `$mdDialog` service which does the injection of the controller.

Under the hood, the `$mdDialog` service uses the [$controller Service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$controller) to inject the specified controller.